# How to expand all after DataSource Read is finished loading on Telerik MVC TreeView (Kendo UI)

Tags: telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

How would I get my TreeView to expand once the data is loaded?

```
        @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                .Name("OrganizationTree")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "demo-section" })
                .DataTextField("Name")
                .DragAndDrop(true)
                .ExpandAll(true)
                .Events(events => events
                        .Select("onOrgSelect")
                        .Drop("onOrgDrop")
                )
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Model(m=> m 
                        .Id("ID")
                        .HasChildren("HasChildren")
                    )
                    .Read(read => read
                        .Action("Organizations_Read", "Organizations")
                    )
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  It's different than what was posted in Petur's link since it's not pure "Kendo UI" but instead it's Telerik's "UI for ASPNET MVC" that uses Kendo UI's framework.

```
        @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                .Name("OrganizationTree")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "demo-section" })
                .DataTextField("Name")
                .DragAndDrop(true)
                .ExpandAll(true)
                .Events(events => events
                        .Select("onOrgSelect")
                        .Drop("onOrgDrop")
                        .DataBound("onDataBound")  //I ADDED THIS HERE
                )
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Model(m=> m 
                        .Id("ID")
                        .HasChildren("HasChildren")
                    )
                    .Read(read => read
                        .Action("Organizations_Read", "Organizations")
                    )
                )
        )
```

And this I needed this function in the head tag:

```
<script>
    function onDataBound(e)
    {
        $("#OrganizationTree").data("kendoTreeView").expand(".k-item")
    }
</script>
```